# How to do kerberos authentication for Clickhouse HDFS disk?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, clickhouse

In clickhouse documentation it is explained how to add hdfs disk by providing [URL](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/storing-data/)

```
<clickhouse>
    <storage_configuration>
        <disks>
            <hdfs>
                <type>hdfs</type>
                <endpoint>hdfs://hdfs1:9000/clickhouse/</endpoint>
            </hdfs>
        </disks>
        ...
    </storage_configuration>
</clickhouse>
```

However, HDFS only supports kerberos authentication, it is not possible to auth with [URL](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/hdfs/).
Clickhouse also explains how to set up kerberos auth for HDFS engine here.

```
<!-- Global configuration options for HDFS engine type -->
  <hdfs>
    <hadoop_kerberos_keytab>/tmp/keytab/clickhouse.keytab</hadoop_kerberos_keytab>
    <hadoop_kerberos_principal>clickuser@TEST.CLICKHOUSE.TECH</hadoop_kerberos_principal>
    <hadoop_security_authentication>kerberos</hadoop_security_authentication>
  </hdfs>

  <!-- Configuration specific for user "root" -->
  <hdfs_root>
    <hadoop_kerberos_principal>root@TEST.CLICKHOUSE.TECH</hadoop_kerberos_principal>
  </hdfs_root>
```

How to configure kerberos for HDFS disk in MergeTree engine?

Comment: Are you asking how to actually setup Kerberos for Hadoop? That's too broad for Stackoverflow, and it's mostly already documented in Hadoop official documentation

Comment: I am asking how to create a config in clickhouse that will auth with kerberos. Consider HDFS side is already set

Comment: You've already linked to the documentation for it, so what exactly have you tried or what isn't clear?

Comment: The documentation does not provide a way to setup kerberos for a hdfs disk in MergeTree engine, it does only for HDFS engine. If it is clear to you how to do this, please answer

Comment: I'm only here because the `hadoop` tag. I don't use Clickhouse, but the engine shouldn't matter. Kerberos is specific to HDFS and its client. More specifically, HDFS is an integration, not a part of the MergeTree Families, according to the docs.

Comment: From what I can understand [ClickHouse needs its own Kerberos user](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/external-authenticators/kerberos/#enabling-kerberos-in-clickhouse). You then allow that user to access your HDFS cluster via a keytab, defined in the HDFS integration settings.